# Question where the users can add / append the answers to make a big list

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it possible to have a question where the users can append  the answer so that, we can have a big list on main site.

For clarity sake, if we have  a question on  red-ox reagents, users can keep adding, and finally we will have a list of all the literature reported red-ox reagents.

Answer (score 3):

List questions are generally disliked across the network, with a few exceptions.

We are not Wikipedia. We do not want to be a repository of all human knowledge.

Such questions aren't really a fit for our voting system. Also, they can (in general)  become opinionated and deteriorate.

Comment: I mean some thing similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list

Comment: @Anil that doesn't mean they don't hate it. We have that on Physics.SE as well, but we close any new ones.. Also, math.SE is a sort of maverick in terms of policy.

Comment: I do believe that wiki is suited for that. In fact, most of the SEs does not have long-list / big-list. But, to understand policy on this SE, i have raised this question.

Comment: @Anil CW is not a way to justify offtopic/notconstructive questions. Not  anymore, anyway. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: if that is the case, we can close this question.

Comment: @Anil no no leave it open. This post is still constructive for site-building (what meta is for), and should stay open. Others may wanto put their 2¢ as well. Usually per-site metas don't need the closing of questions.

Comment: Its alright. I dont have the in-depth knowledge of all these stuffs.

Comment: It seems this is [site depended](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-manage-big-lists). [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) has [quite a number of big list questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), some of them really popular. But then again: they _do_ consider themselves some kind of knowledge database for TeX related stuff. It obviously depends on what the community wants. And maybe topics like TeX are better suited for these kinds of questions than chemistry or physics?

Comment: @Clem yeah, TeX is human-made and its not too hard to get a repo of all TeX knowledge. Chem is much more vast.

Comment: @Manishearth say that again when you setting your first document with LaTeX -- just kidding ;)